# Normalisation in Dirac Notation

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, wavefunction, normalization

Say I have a wave function as follows (example):

$$|\psi\rangle=|\phi_1\rangle-\sqrt{3}|\phi_2\rangle+ 2i|\phi_3\rangle$$

I know normalisation means:

$$\langle \Psi_N|\Psi_N \rangle =1\tag{1}$$

I know how to normalise using functions:

say $\Psi_N=c\psi$, then:

$$c^2\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\psi^*\psi \mathrm{d}V=1$$

But I don't know how to solve $(1)$?

Comment: What is known about the $|\phi_i ⟩$? Are they normalized?

Comment: @Jakob If the $|\phi_i\rangle$ aren't normalised then $|\psi\rangle$ can't be normalised? Correct?

Comment: No. Using $\langle \psi|\psi\rangle = c\in \mathbb R$ you can define $|\psi\rangle_N\equiv \frac{1}{\sqrt{c}}|\psi\rangle$ which is normalized.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that the conjugate of $|\Psi\rangle$ is the sum of the conjugates of its parts.

The question as stated is incomplete, but I will make the assumption that $|\phi_1\rangle$, $|\phi_2\rangle$, and $|\phi_3\rangle$ are themselves [normalized and orthogonal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthonormality#Definition). If that's the case, then
$$
\langle\psi|\psi\rangle = \langle\phi_1|\phi_1\rangle + 3\langle\phi_2|\phi_2\rangle+4\langle\phi_3|\phi_3\rangle =1+3+4=8.
$$
All of the cross-terms from the application of the conjugate of the sum, like $\langle\phi_1|\phi_2\rangle$, are zero because of orthogonality.
So,
$$
|\psi_N\rangle = {1\over2\sqrt{2}}|\psi\rangle
$$

Comment: Thank you. Understood!